# Flutter how can import stateful widget

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to learn Flutter.I found this article for some animated input field and I want to use it but I can't import this to my mainapp. How can I make it

https://medium.com/@mjpublicuser/flutter-challenge-animated-text-form-field-884dff3140f0

The github files

https://github.com/manojeeva/flutter_chellange_animated_text_form_field

My try is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'test_page.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          TestPage()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Code and structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsSWn.png)

Comment: If you are starting to learn Flutter, your choice is --in my own opinion-- for intermediate level. My advice is, take a step back and learn from the basics (such as assets importing, using a package, etc). Happy developing.

Comment: Okay I will, 'ı'm not new at proggramming new in Flutter I can import some helper package but,thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you have a problem with **import**? Please, post the error message.

I see error in your code, you missed argument name, it should be:

```
...
body: Center(
 child: TestPage(),
),
...
```

Also check if you have file `test_page.dart` in the same folder as `main.dart`.

Comment: Yes I got this files